# "Successful applications in engineering outpace mathematical rigor" - other way 'round?

Tags: soft-question

I saw the above quote on [Jeremy Kun's](http://jeremykun.com/tag/convolution/) and it really hit a note with me.  This was in the context of the Fourier transform, in that physicists were using it to discover elegant identities before there was a rigorous mathematical foundation for it.

I am curious to learn of instances in which this occured in reverse; that is, a purely mathemtical discovery has found successful applications in the applied or social sciences.  By purely mathematical, I mean the only incentive for discovering it was the spirit of better understanding - as opposed to, solving a technical problem from physics or engineering.  For example, **Ito's stochastic integration** along with **martingale theory** allowed for a revolutionary method of pricing financial derivatives, from which an entire new profession (financial engineering) followed.  In particular, it was financial economists (Black, Scholes and Merton) who **used the new mathematical results to solve a previously unsolved problem**.  On the other hand the development of Monte Carlo integration was motivated by the technical need of the atomic bomb development.

I am soliciting other examples for when people ask, "what is this stuff you're doing good for, anyways?"

Comment: This question may be better received on http://hsm.stackexchange.com/